# Is it possible to use inclusive lower bound in aggregation queries?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

After reading https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.min/#cursor-min it seems that `$min` is deprecated an no longer supported in mongo >= 3.2

I want to include a lower bound into my aggregation pipeline, so that I could get documents after some other document.

I was thinking about using `$bucket` but it doesn't support strings as its `boundaries` and also at least 2 boundaries should be provided. This is not what I need as I'm trying to implement a cursor-based pagination according to Relay specification where a cursor is an id https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm

Also, ids in the collection are uuids, that's why using something like `$min` would be preferable

Answer (score 1):

You are getting docs wrong.

`cursor.min()` is not deprecated. What's deprecated is use of `$min` query modifier **in mongo shell**.

It has nothing to do with aggregation. The simplest lower bound in aggregation is a `$match: { field: { $gte:value } }` stage